# How to enable Markdown code block line numbers

Tags: sublimetext2, markdown, codehighlighter

I installed Markdown Preview in Sublime Text 2, and already set

```
"enable_highlight": true,
"enable_pygments": true,
```

I also set the following code in the file `codehilite.py`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # define default configs
    self.config = {
        'linenums': [True, "Use lines numbers. True=yes, False=no, None=auto"],
        'force_linenos' : [Force, "Depreciated! Use 'linenums' instead. Force line numbers - Default: False"],
        'guess_lang' : [True, "Automatic language detection - Default: True"],
        'css_class' : ["codehilite",
                       "Set class name for wrapper <div> - Default: codehilite"],
        'pygments_style' : ['default', 'Pygments HTML Formatter Style (Colorscheme) - Default: default'],
        'noclasses': [True, 'Use inline styles instead of CSS classes - Default false']
        }

    super(CodeHiliteExtension, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, I still cannot see the line numbers in the rendered view. What extra settings are needed?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sublime Text 3 and have just installed sublime-markdown-preview and was also looking for a way to get nice coloring and linenumbers in the code-block.
The instructions https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview
describe to put the line `codehilite(linenums=True)` into your settings. So I use:

```
{ 
   "github_mode": "gfm", 
   "parser": "github",     
   "build_action": "browser", 
   "enabled_extensions": [
        "extra", "github", 
       "codehilite(guess_lang=False, pygments_style=github, linenums=True)" ]
}
```

in my user settings and it works.